# Can someone explain this simple syntax to me

Tags: python, loops, iterator

can someone give me a very quick explanation of what this code does :

```
  for j in range(len(word)):
        if word[j] in key:
            newString = newString+key[word[j]]
```

Obviously the code above makes no sense but  i really just want to know what putting j in the brackets beside word does ? I am familiary with for loops like for i in word and if word in key but what does if word(j) in key mean

Comment: `word` is a sequence like `string`, `list` etc. `word[j]` is fetching particular element at position `j`.

Comment: Please, no caMelCaSe, please! it's Python, local variable here could be `rv` or `filtered` or in the worst case, `new_string` ref: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting in simpler form :

```
for chr in word:
    if chr in key:
        newString = newString + key[chr]
```

I think It'll help you to understand stuff very well.

Answer (score 0):

The `[j]` next to word is pointing at the element at the "j"th position in `word` (which is presumably iterable). So if `word` was `"hello"` and `j` was 1, `word[j]` would be `"e"` (since numbering starts from 0).

Comment: ok thanks . so if i have word = ("hello)   int= len(word)    for i in range(int):    print i[2]    should just not print 1 for me ? Im getting an error about int object has no attribute get_item